# C Programming File I/O

Tags: c, file-io

I'm trying to read from a text file and write to one, but every time I execute my code, nothing happens with the text files. By "nothing happens", I mean that the program won't read my input file and no data is exported into my output file. Could someone point out why it is not working? Thanks for any help given in advance. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *inptr, *outptr; 

int main() {
    int a, b, c;
    inptr = fopen("trianglein.txt","r"); //Initialization of pointer and opening of file trianglein.txt
    outptr = fopen("triangleout.txt","w"); //Initialization of pointer and opening of file triangleout.txt

    while((fscanf(inptr,"%d %d %d",&a, &b, &c))!= EOF){  
        fprintf(outptr,"\n%2d %2d %2d\n",a,b,c); 
        if(a+b>c && b+c>a && c+a>b){
            fprintf(outptr, "This is a triangle.\n"); 
            if(a !=b && b !=c && a!=c){ 
                fprintf(outptr, "This is a scalene triangle.\n");
                if(a==b && a==c && c==b){
                    fprintf(outptr, "This is an equilateral triangle.\n");
                    if(a*a+b*b==c*c || b*b+c*c==a*a || a*a+c*c==b*b){
                        fprintf(outptr, "This is a right trianlge.\n");
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`trianglein.txt` contents:

```
10 12 15
2 3 7
3 4 5
6 9 5
6 6 6
6 8 10
7 7 9
```

Comment: It seems to work for me. As in when I run it triangleout.txt contains stuff. Can you post the contents of your trianglein.txt. (Also you might want to relook at your logic because the right triangle is not an equilateral triangle.)

Comment: btw, you might want to restructure your code using "continue" – that would let you avoid that huge amount of indentation

Comment: If nothing happens then there's no file "trianglein.txt" in working directory. Check return of fopen. Put file in working directory, if this is a case. Also check content of "trianglein.txt". Using debugger is good idea btw.

Comment: @Cranderberry can you put that in the question. As there is no formatting in the comment.

Comment: I suspect that it's due to newline encoding problem. Windows uses `\r\n` to encode newlines, while Unix-like systems uses `\n`.

Comment: @CarealManic: That, too, cannot be the problem. Since `fopen` has not been passed the `b` flag, the files are opened in text mode, where the newlines read are normalized to `\n`, no matter what they were in the file.

Comment: Hmm, tried changing \n to \r\n and still no change. Could it be some administrative rights on windows? I'm already the administrator.

Comment: @Cranderberry did you changed the `\n` in trianglein.txt to `\r\n` , or changed `\n` to `\r\n` in the code? There's no use to change it in the code.

Comment: @icktoofay I suspect that the file uses `\n` to end a line and Windows expects a `\r\n`. This **might** cause problems. BTW, I am not familiar with Windows. I may be wrong.

Comment: I'm running this right now on bloodshed on windows. I'm going to try running it on codeblocks on linux in a second.

Comment: Remind me, what file extension do i use on linux? is it also .txt?

Comment: @Cranderberry It doesn't matter.

Comment: It seems that I was wrong (again!). I have run this program in Windows. It works.

Comment: @Cranderberry Can you give us the hexdump of the file? If you are in linux, just give us the output of `hexdump trianglein.txt`

Comment: When I try to run on linux via codeblocks:

http://tinypic.com/r/a5c5mq/5

Still no change to triangleout.txt

Comment: @Cranderberry It seems that something goes wrong with the file `trianglein.txt`. Again, can you please give us the hexdump of `trianglein.txt`?

Comment: Sorry, not too familiar with linux. Can you walk me through finding hexdump?

Comment: @Cranderberry launch terminal. Type `hexdump <the path to trianglein.txt>` . Then show us the output.

Comment: I'm doing hexdump </home/craig/Documents/trianglein.txt> and it's giving me a "syntax error unexpected token 'newline'"

Comment: @Cranderberry type `hexdump /home/craig/Documents/trianglein.txt`. You don't need to type the brackets. :)

Comment: 0000000 3031 3120 2032 3531 320a 3320 3720 330a
0000010 3420 3520 360a 3920 3520 360a 3620 3620
0000020 360a 3820 3120 0a30 2037 2037 0a39     
000002e

Comment: @Cranderberry REALLY strange. The exactly same file works on my machine.

Comment: @Cranderberry let's do one more thing. Try compiling and running this code: https://ideone.com/78Wel8 . Then show me the output of the program.

Comment: No change to output file. The console states: "error: : No such file or directory"

Comment: @Cranderberry Problem found. As the error message describe, the problem is "No such file or directory", i.e. the file is not found. Working directory is a directory that you are currently in. The file `trianglein.txt` must be inside the working directory. Put `trianglein.txt` into the working directory and run the program again. This should work.

Comment: Haha, sorry once more. By put it in the working directory, do you mean in the same directory as the compiler? Right now it is in my /home/craig/Documents folder.

Comment: @Cranderberry aww... It depends on the IDE if you execute the program via your IDE. If you are launching the program in terminal, you can get the working directory with the command `pwd` in linux. I guess that you are running the program via an IDE. Are you using codeblock?

Comment: Yes. I'm using 10.05, Not using terminal to launch

Comment: In the toolbar, click `project->propterties` . Then click the tab `bulid targets`. You should see something like `Output filename` and `Execution working dir`. Change `Output filename` to `program` and `Execution working dir` to `.` . Then copy/move the file `trianglein.txt` to the same directory as the `program` located. It should work then.

Comment: It works! You are the best! Thanks for working through this with me.

Comment: `if(a !=b && b !=c && a!=c)` and `if(a==b && a==c && c==b)` It's a contradictory conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple problems.

Firstly, you need to check if inptr and outptr are valid by testing against NULL.

Secondly, fscanf can return either EOF, 0 or > 0.

If your input file doesn't contain valid input.

Also there are problems in that you can get 3 ints read successfull, or 2 ints or 1 and the value of a, b and c are only optionally set.

If no conversion took place on the input then the value of zero is returned in which case the while loop will exit.

Also bear in mind that with the scanf style functions this input will succeed and return the value of 1.

> "1rubbish"

I think what you may want is something like the following:

```
// Somewhere near the top
#include <stderr.h>
// ... other includes

const char* inname = "trianglein.txt";
const char* outname = "triangleout.txt";

// Any other stuff


// Inside main...

// Initialization of pointer and opening of file trianglein.txt
if ((inptr = fopen(inname,"r")) == 0){
  fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s: %s", inname, strerror(inname));
  return -1;
}

// Initialization of pointer and opening of file triangleout.txt
if ((outptr = fopen(outname,"w")) == 0){
  fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s: %s", outname, strerror(outname));
  return -1;
}


int result;
while(true){
  result = fscanf(inptr,"%d %d %d",&a, &b, &c);
  if (result == EOF)
    break;

  if (result < 3)  // Ignore incomplete lines
    continue;

  // do the normal stuff
}
```

Comment: Although the "testing against NULL" is semantically correct, and your code correctly uses `if(!inptr)`, the two don't match each other.  An `if(input != NULL)` would explicitly match, but hardly anyone bothers.  The idiom tends to be `if(inptr = fopen("trianglein.txt") ...`, using an assignment in the test.

Comment: True, and I'd probably write it that way normally.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is working fine in my system. I use `Code::Blocks 10.05` on `Windows 7`.

The only possibility of a logical error occurs when you have the file trianglein.txt with less than 3 integer values to be read by the `fscanf()`. For example `trianglein.txt` file with values `1`, `1 2`, `1 2 3 4`, `1 2 3 4 5` etc. will give incorrect values to the variables `b` and/or `c`. So initialize `a=-1`, `b=-1`, `c=-1` before the execution of each iteration of the loop and check them after reading.

If you are running the program check the file `triangleout.txt` for access rights. Some times you may not have write access on that particular file.

By the way the classification logic is wrong. An equilateral triangle can not be a right angled one.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting

```
fclose(inptr);
```

and

```
fclose(outptr);
```

at the end of your code.

Comment: +1. I believe that it helps. @thejh can you please explain your idea?

Comment: Repeating my comment on Careal Manic's answer, this will not help: As per the C99 draft N1256 §7.20.4.3 ¶4, all streams are flushed on program termination.

Comment: It won't help the question's direct problem, but it *is* good style to clean up resources even in main(), and it's essential in larger programs.  Besides, the querant didn't mention whether a C99 compiler is involved.

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: As suggested by icktoofay, this answer is wrong.

You have to do `fclose()` or `fflush()` in order to get the data written to the file.
Insert these code right before `return 0;`

```
fclose(inptr);
fclose(outptr);
```

Comment: No. As per the C99 draft N1256 §7.20.4.3 ¶4, all streams are flushed on program termination.

Comment: @icktoofay Oh well, you are right. I've just compiled the code. It works. I am not going to delete this answer anyway.

Comment: @Cranderberry: it may not have done anything but it's good practice to close your file resources when you're done with them. In this case, because your program terminates directly after - it's handled(not true in all languages), but it won't always be so.